# "No specific subroutine for the generic" error with MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have installed OpenMPI and it works with a simple parallelized hello world program but it doesn't work when `MPI_SEND()` or `MPI_RECV()` is called. I am using gfortran 5.1 and OpenMPI 3.0.1rc4.

The error is

> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at
>   (1)

It seems the compiler does not recognise basic subroutines such as `MPI_RECV()`.

This is the test program that causes the error:

```
program main

use mpi

implicit none

integer :: ierr,np,myid,i,rbuf

integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: ista

CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)

CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid,ierr) 

CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,np,ierr) 


allocate(ista(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,np))


if (myid==0) then

   do i = 1, np-1

        CALL MPI_RECV(rbuf,1,MPI_INTEGER4,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ista,ierr)

        write(*,"('process ',i2,' sent:',i2)") i,rbuf

     end do

else

     i=10*myid

     CALL MPI_SEND(i,1,MPI_INTEGER4,0,myid,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

end if

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end program main
```

Comment: This is because you are calling the subroutine with parameters that do not match the signature. Post a [MCVE] so we can have a look.

Comment: I have added a test program that doesn't work. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

The status argument is an `INTEGER(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)`, and you pass `ista` which is declared as a 2D array, that is why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: So how should I have to modify the test?

Comment: You don't mean `integer(mpi_status_size)` in the sense of `integer(kind=mpi_status_size)`?

Comment: @francescalus No, it is indeed an array.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, perhaps closer to the original intent of your code, is to pass the appropriate subarray `ista(:,i)` of the array of all statuses

```
    CALL MPI_RECV(rbuf,1,MPI_INTEGER4,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ista(:,i),ierr)
```

Or just use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`, I think it is the best here.

Comment: good point, if the status is not going to be used, then `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` is the best choice !

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: It compiles but when it runs it appears: 
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

Comment: @VladimirF do you have any idea?

Comment: Your program does NOT crash on my computer. You can ask a new question. Make sure the code is exact and you show the complete input. Compile with all error checking options you have (for example,  `mpif90 -g -fcheck=all -Wall`).

Comment: @VladimirF it works using mpif90 -g test.f90 but it doesn't work with mpif90 -o test test.f90. The compilation works in both cases but mpirun works only with the -g option. Can you explain me why? In my real problem, I need to create an executable linking different .o files so I need the -o option

Comment: You are doing something wrong. There is always the option of renaming the output, but this is really something for a **new question**. Show the exact code, library versions, compiler versions, compiler options and the output. Use all debugging options your compiler has.